# Dockerize stack: MapServer - AngularJs web app - Lumen API - PostgreSQL

Tags: angularjs, apache, postgresql, docker, mapserver

I'm trying to solve some of my question regarding the architecture of a system consisting of the following:

- AngularJS web application frontend
- MapServer generating & serving map images through WMS
- Lumen REST API backend containing all the business logic
- PostgreSQL database with PostGIS to store spatial data

---

Which is the proper way to dockerize that kind of stack?

Currently i'm thinking of the following containers to be created:

1. Web Server containing:

   - Apache web server
   - AngularJS frontend application
2. Map Server containing:

   - Apache web server with CGI support
   - MapServer CGI application
   - MapCache/TileCache
3. Application Server container:

   - Apache web server
   - Lumen API backend
4. Database containing:

   - PostgreSQL relational database
   - PostGIS add-on

The list of components of each container has not been yet finalized, so some of them may not fit exactly where they have been placed. For example, should Apache be on a separate container?

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about docker philosophy, Microservices.

> Microservices is an approach to application development in which a
>   large application is built as a suite of modular services. Each module
>   supports a specific business goal and uses a simple, well-defined
>   interface to communicate with other modules.

Meaning we need to split our system into microservices, and put each microservice into a container. This will help you significantly when you try to upgrade your application.

In your case, I would separate apache from angular js container.